# ASP.net: Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed. Javascript two parameters Eval and static text

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using Linkbutton in datagridview and onClientclick calling a javascript with two parameters. 1st parameter is database field value and 2nd parameter is a StaticText. but I am getting 'The server tag is not well formed' for below code

**'  runat="server" onclientclick="getlableText('<%#Eval("Order ID") %>','staticText')" > linkbutton**

Kindly advise me as how to achieve this.

Comment: Try changing `OnClientClick` to use composite formatting with escaped single quotes like this: `OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("getLabelText(\'{0}\', \'staticText\')", Eval("Order ID")) %>'`.

Comment: Hi Tetsuya i'm still getting the same error.